# Java ExecutorService and updating a commonly used ressource

Tags: java, multithreading, data-processing

I am trying to implement a heavy computation process on a Data array.

To do so, I used Executor service to be able to get the result of each processing while exploiting CPU's full capabilities.

However, I need to feed the next thread working on the array with the result I get from the previously executed thread without having to wait for all the threads to terminate.

By other terms, shared_ressource array is a common attribute to all DATAItem objects and it's modified by each thread (DATAItem object).

I want that the modification could be perceived by the next DATAItem object in the for loop (replaced by a While loop here) using threads.

```
  int np = Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors();
  ExecutorService pool = new ThreadPoolExecutor(np-2, np-2, 5000,TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS,new LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable>());
 // shared_ressource is the array of objects from class SharedRessource to be modified by each thread
    int i = 0;
    while (i<shared_ressource.size())
    {
        if (((ThreadPoolExecutor) pool).getActiveCount()<=(np-2) )
       {
         DATAItem di = new DATAItem();
         di.setSharedRessource(shared_ressource);

         Future<List<SharedRessource>> DataItemMod = pool.submit(di);
         // the Future's .get() method returns the modified shared_ressource array  
        i++;
       }
       else
           try {Thread.sleep(100);}
          catch (InterruptedException e) {e.printStackTrace();}

    }

         pool.shutdown();
```

Is that possible ?

Otherwise, how could I do that while benefiting from the full CPU's multi-threading capacities ?

Comment: your description of the problem needs some work. 
It's not clear if how you are splitting the work.

Comment: @Daniel Sperry what should I explain exactly ?

Comment: How exactly is each DATAItem (I suppose it's a callable) modifying the original array? in place? creating a new array with a few extra elements?
If it's really modifying the original array, in place, then how do you prevent messing up with the input of the other DATAItems?

Perhaps describing your actual problem would help.

Answer (score 0):

You are planning to do sequential processing, so even if you are using threads..the second thread cannot process parallel to the first thread since
it is waiting for the first to terminate.
Maybe you can look into join feature of threads where join makes a thread
wait for another thread to complete execution.